# How to create a variable in IIB which has scope for each single flow?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I need to create a variable in IIB flow which has to be available through out the flow. I have gone through the variables creation in documentation. As per my understanding, I should create a SHARED variable in ESQL module. But in documentation its mentioned as "Subsequent messages can access the data left by a previous message." which I didn't understand.

Could anyone please suggest how to create a variable which should have scope only for that flow(only per each request/instance)?

For example if I have to capture total value of some elements in payload and store calculated value in the created variable which I can use across all the nodes throughout the flow .

Comment: If you're worried about subsequent messages accessing what is in said variable, can't you just zero it out at the end of the flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac12620_.htm) tree structure can be used for your use case:

> The environment tree differs from the local environment tree in that a single instance of it is maintained throughout the message flow.
>
> When the message flow processing is complete, the Environment tree is discarded.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Steinmann, Thanks for the reply.Could you please elaborate when to use environment and local environment variables.

Comment: @Ramakrishna I usually use the [Local Environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac00520_.htm) when I need to access information from a previous node (e.g. `InputLocalEnvironment.File.Name` for the file name) or when I need to configure the next node (e.g. `OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL` to set the URL for an HTTP call). The [Global Environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac12620_.htm) I use for example to store a copy of the input message for later usage.

Comment: I would suggest you to read IBM doc about it, it's a must read and it is a bit more complex than explained above, even if it was correct ;) : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.doc/gop_03/topics/bj60052_.htm